# mySQL count table efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: myTable]

Basically I have a table name myTable and inside has Name,Class , I would like to sort them out like the table below with a count of each name and number of 1,2,3s they have.Below is the codes I currently had but it work on small amount of entries, if the table has 20,000 lines it took a very long time to execute.

```
Select DISTINT(Name),
       (Select count(*) from `myTable` d1 where d1.Name = dd.Name and Class=1),
       (Select count(*) from `myTable` d2 where d2.Name = dd.Name and Class=2),
       (Select count(*) from `myTable` d3 where d3.Name = dd.Name and Class=3)
from `myTable` dd
Order by Name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is classic conditional aggregation:

```
Select Name,
       sum(case when Class = 1 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when Class = 2 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when Class = 3 then 1 else 0 end)
from myTable
group by Name
```

Comment: thanks for your efficient answer, the query time for 50,000 entries is so much faster now.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY` with conditional counting:

```
select Name,
       count(case when class = 1 then 1 end),
       count(case when class = 2 then 1 end),
       count(case when class = 3 then 1 end)
from `myTable`
group by Name;
```

**Note:**
`DISTINCT` is not a function on a column, it works on the whole selected rows. (It doesn't matter if the column-name is put within parentheses or not.)

```
select distinct(col1), col2, ...
```

is the same as

```
select distinct col1, col2, ...
```

and also the same as

```
select distinct col1, (col2), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot it:

```
SELECT t.Name,
    SUM(if(t.Class=1,1,null)) as Class1,
    SUM(if(t.Class=2,1,null)) as Class2,
    SUM(if(t.Class=3,1,null)) as Class3
FROM myTable t
GROUP BY t.Name
```